# login form : how to detect 2 conditions?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

With Selenium, I want to fill a login form.
When I click send button, there are two possibilities.

If login/password are good, there is a redirect to page "index.htm" :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
try:
    wait.until(driver.current_url == url + "/index.htm")
except TimeoutException:
    print("      Bad redirect")
    return False
return True
```

If login/password are bad, there is no redirect : "login.htm" is reloaded with a error message "bad login/password" :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#error")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("      Bad login/password")
    return False
return True
```

I know how to detect this 2 conditions individualy but how to do with one test ?

Comment: You'd just add the element error  to the except of the login passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda a: driver.current_url ==
                               url + "/index.htm" or EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#error"))(driver))
```

until expects a function , so define a lamda function, and EC returns a method that returns true or false . Just call it by passing driver